# Atribuir a uma variável uma Data Dinâmica?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, tsql

Meu Objetivo é criar uma procedure em *SQL Server*, que tem por parâmetro padrão duas variáveis, uma com a data inicial de `(hoje - 3 anos)` e outra como data final igual a `hoje`. Já utilizo para outras operações (por exemplo um between) esse formato de pegar a data.

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
    Create procedure EXTRAÇÃO_SD1_SD2
-- Receber data formato 'AAAMMDD'
    @dataini VARCHAR(MAX) = REPLACE(CONVERT(char(10), GetDate()-1080,126),'-','')
    @datafim as varchar(10) = REPLACE(CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126),'-','')
As 
Begin 
-- continua procedure
```

Porém recebo o erro abaixo ao executar

> Msg 102, Nível 15, Estado 1, Procedimento EXTRAÇÃO_SD1_SD2, Linha 5 [Linha de Início do Lote 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.

O que há de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você usou a parte errada da *procedure* para fazer suas atribuições.  Antes do `begin` é a declaração da identidade da *procedure*, e dentro, o corpo.
Na parte da identidade você poderá definir os parâmetros de entrada, isso se desejar utilizar uma data de referência informada pelo usuário, descartando por exemplo, o uso fixo do `GetDate`.

Veja como poderia ficar este seu código de forma que se for passado algum valor, ele será usado, senão, o `GetDate` será invocado:
*Veja também que não foi necessário retirar os '-' para realizar a subtração.*

```
Create procedure EXTRAÇÃO_SD1_SD2 (@dataini varchar(10) = null, @datafim varchar(10) = null)
As 
Begin    
    --Para indicar a procedure que o usuário está passando datas no formato YYYYMMDD
    --Se não garantir isso, e estiver configurado como dmy vai dar erro na sua procedure
    set dateformat 'ymd'

    declare @dataI varchar(10) = convert(date, dateadd(year, -3, coalesce(@dataini, GetDate())))
    declare @dataF varchar(10) = convert(date, coalesce(@datafim, GETDATE()))

    ...
end
```

Como complemento, fiz uso de outras funções:

**`Set DateFormat`** -> É necessário porque se o servidor estiver com outro formado, os meses poderão ser trocados pelos dias por exemplo;

**`DateAdd`** -> Utilizada para fazer a subtração de 3 anos;

**`Coalesce`** -> Se nenhum valor for passado aos parâmetros, então irá buscar um valor do GetDate;

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, fiz daquela maneira pois como falei gostaria que essas variáveis tivessem um valor padrão **quando** não existisse parâmetro na chamada da procedure. Segui o exemplo dado neste site (https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189330(v=sql.105).aspx).  Vou fazer um teste com o seu exemplo

Comment: Atribuições simples de valor são permitidas, o que não poderá fazer é o uso de funções onde são declaradas as variáveis.

Comment: Ok, neste caso pelo que entendi não tem solução ao caso apresentado certo? Ou seja se eu alterar da maneira que você indicou as variáveis '@dataini' e '@datafim' terão sempre o valor : REPLACE(CONVERT(char(10), GetDate()-1080,126),'-','') e REPLACE(CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126),'-','') respectivamente, correto @Ismael ?

Comment: Isso mesmo Bruno. Vou atualizar a resposta e incluir os parâmetros e permitir um valor dinâmico a estas variáveis.